# How to use helpers on webgrid

Tags: partial-views, html-helper, webgrid

I'm trying to add a *partialView* inside  a format attr  in a *WebGrid* but I getting this error *Error 47  An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation*

This is the code:

```
   @grid.GetHtml(
   footerStyle: "paging",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    firstText: "<< First",
    previousText: "< Prev",
    nextText: "Next >",
    lastText: "Last >>",
    columns: new[] {
    grid.Column("Name",header: "Name",
    format: 
     @<text>    
       <div>
        @foreach (var i in item.list)
           { 
              <div class="content">
               @Html.Partial("Menu", i.Type)
             </div>

            }
    </div>
</text>),})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. I hope it will help you

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns:
grid.Columns(
grid.Column("Partialview", format: @<text>@Html.Partial("Menu", (int)@item.Type)</text>)))
```

For partial view I have passed integer model. You can pass required model